# How to save the documentID in a document in Firebase using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called `favoritePost` in Firebase and that collection has several fields that get data from my app, one of the fields is the `id` that needs to be the `documentID` that is generated when the document is created, the issue is that I'm using too much code to achieve this result and I'm also getting an error for about 2 seconds when the document is being created.

I would like to know if there is a better implement this and how to fix the error.

**Here I create the collection**

The issue is here, when the collection is being created I get an error in my homepage because this document does not have data, it just creates the fields and I can't use `docref.documentId`  inside the fields, so I have to create a new method that updates this collection and saves the data including the `docref.documentId`.

```
final docsref = await favRef
          .document(widget.currentUserId)
          .collection('favoritePost')
          .add(
        {
          'imageUrl': '',
          'caption': '',
          'likeCount': 0,
          'authorId': '',
          'timestamp': '',
          'userName': '',
          'userImage': '',
          'id': '',
          'idSecondPost': '',
          'experience': '',
          'cSrateStars': '',
          'productName': '',
          'brand': '',
          'cost': '',
          'envioDiasRateStars': '',
          'easyPurchaseRateStars': '',
          'totalRate': '',
          'businessName': '',
          'recomendation': '',
          'videoLink': '',
        },
      );
```

**Here I pass some data including the `docsref.documentID` to my database file**

```
DatabaseService.addFavorite(
          currentUserId: widget.currentUserId,
          post: widget.reviews,
          docref: docsref.documentID);
```

**Here the data is saved into the collection created before, now I'm able to include the `docsref.documentID` into the `id` field**

```
static void addFavorite(
      {String idReview,
      Reviews post,
      String currentUserId,
      String toId,
      String docref}) {
    DocumentReference postRef = reviewRef.document(post.idReview);
    postRef.get().then(
      (doc) {
        final docsref = favRef
            .document(currentUserId)
            .collection('favoritePost')
            .document(docref)
            .updateData({
          'imageUrl': post.imageUrl,
          'caption': post.comments,
          'likeCount': post.likeCount,
          'authorId': post.authorId,
          'timestamp': post.timestamp,
          'userName': post.userName,
          'userImage': post.userImage,
          'idReview': post.idReview,
          'experience': post.address,
          'cSrateStars': post.cSrateStars,
          'productName': post.productName,
          'brand': post.brand,
          'cost': post.cost,
          'envioDiasRateStars': post.envioDiasRateStars,
          'easyPurchaseRateStars': post.easyPurchaseRateStars,
          'totalRate': post.totalRate,
          'businessName': post.businessName,
          'recomendation': post.recomendation,
          'id': docref,
          'videoLink': post.videoLink,
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting in the homepage?

Comment: null values, but it just takes like 2 seconds

Comment: Since the answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as correct by clicking the check mark next to it, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the `documentID` in the homepage by doing the following:

```
var randomDoc = await favRef
          .document(widget.currentUserId)
          .collection('favoritePost')
          .document();
```

By using `document()` without a path, it will generate a document id for you, and then you can do:

```
final docsref = await favRef
          .document(widget.currentUserId)
          .collection('favoritePost')
          .document(randomDoc.documentID)
          .setData(
        {
          'imageUrl': '',
          'caption': '',
          'likeCount': 0,
          'authorId': '',
          'timestamp': '',
          'userName': '',
          'userImage': '',
          'id': '',
          'idSecondPost': '',
          'experience': '',
          'cSrateStars': '',
          'productName': '',
          'brand': '',
          'cost': '',
          'envioDiasRateStars': '',
          'easyPurchaseRateStars': '',
          'totalRate': '',
          'businessName': '',
          'recomendation': '',
          'videoLink': '',
          'docId' : randomDoc.documentID
        },
      );
```

This way you generate the id immediately in the homepage and add it to the `docId` field without needing to update.

Answer (score 2):

```
String collectionRef= 'collectionRef';
String docId = Firestore.instance
    .collection(collectionRef)
    .document()
    .documentID;
var docRef = Firestore.instance
    .collection(collectionRef)
    .document(docId);
```

Then `setData` to `docRef` including `documentId: docId`